# Как следует указывать типы для свойств TypeScript-класса, представляющим собой объект с другими типами?

Tags: typescript

Какие типы следует указать для `foo` и `BAR` в приведённом ниже клссе `ExampleClass`?

```
class ExampleClass {
    private foo = {
        one: 1,
        two: 2
    };

    private static BAR = {
        one: 'one',
        two: 'three'
    }
}
```

Случаи, когда такая аннотация необходимо:

[image]

Текстовая версия:

```
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Bootstrap4AlertsCodeGenerator extends Vue {

  static CONTEXT_CSS_CLASSES: object = {
    PRIMARY: 'primary',
    SECONDARY: 'secondary',
    SUCCESS: 'success',
  };

  contextCssClass: string = Bootstrap4AlertsCodeGenerator.CONTEXT_CSS_CLASSES.SECONDARY;

  public get isSelectContextCssClassRadiobuttonActive(): (contextCssClass: string) => boolean {
    return contextCssClass => this.contextCssClass === contextCssClass;
  }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
TS2339: Property 'SECONDARY' does not exist on type 'object'.
```

Comment: 1. использовать `any` вместо `object` 2. объявить контракт или алиас 3. получать доступ по ключу через квадратные скобки `CONTEXT_CSS_CLASSES['SECONDARY']` ..... Когда вы используете тип `object | Object` - вы говорите компилятору, что `CONTEXT_CSS_CLASSES` - простой объект без атрибутов

Comment: @overthesanity, благодарю Вас за ответ! Первый способ не подходит - ведь основное, ради чего нужен TypeScript - типизация (остальные возможности типа статических полей доступны и в JavaScript с нужными Babel-плагинами). Третий способ тоже не очень - почти хардкодинг. А вот второй уже интереснее.

Comment: @overthesanity, не могли бы Вы привести пример второго способа в ответе на основе кода в вопросе? В [документации](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) к TypeScipt-интерфейсам я не нашел ничего подходящего.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов решения ошибки: убрать указание типа

```
static CONTEXT_CSS_CLASSES = {
  PRIMARY: 'primary',
  SECONDARY: 'secondary',
  SUCCESS: 'success',
};
```

В это случае тип будет выведен автоматически, и ошибка больше не появится.

---

Так же можно напрямую указать тип в объявлении. Узнать тип присваиваемого литерала довольно просто, эту будет тот же литерал, в котором вместо значений свойств будет указан их тип.

Например, литерал

```
{
    PRIMARY: 'primary',
    SECONDARY: 'secondary',
    SUCCESS: 'success',
}
```

Имеет тип

```
{
    PRIMARY: string,
    SECONDARY: string,
    SUCCESS: string
}
```

В итоге определение поля будет выглядеть так:

```
static CONTEXT_CSS_CLASSES: {
        PRIMARY: string,
        SECONDARY: string,
        SUCCESS: string
    } = {
    PRIMARY: 'primary',
    SECONDARY: 'secondary',
    SUCCESS: 'success',
};
```

---

Чтобы немного уменьшить объявление, для указанного типа можно объявить [alias](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases)

```
type customType = {
        PRIMARY: string,
        SECONDARY: string,
        SUCCESS: string
};
static CONTEXT_CSS_CLASSES: customType = {
    PRIMARY: 'primary',
    SECONDARY: 'secondary',
    SUCCESS: 'success',
};
```